# Group and Rank Rows in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a ranking system in a mysql database.

I've found several tutorials on ranking and items here on StackOverflow about ranking individual rows against each other.

However, my issue is that I need to group rows by a user id column, add up the values to a second column grouped by user id, then rank them against other groups of a different user id.

Here's an example of the table I'm using:

```
user_id  km_skied  date_entered
1        34        2010-08-19
3        2         2010-08-23
1        3         2010-08-13
4        23        2010-08-01
3        5         2010-08-02
```

The result printout would be by rank:

Skier Rank:

```
Rank  User ID  Total KM
1     1        37
2     4        23
3     3        7
```

Also, I was wondering how I find the rank for a specific user.  Meaning, if I know what the user id is, can I give them just their rank?  Like say

"Your Rank:  2 of 345"

That is the second part of this.

Anyone know how to do that?
Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.
I was able to come up with an answer based on the following Query:

```
$totalQuery = "SELECT SUM(track_length) as usertracklength, username, MAX(track_create_time) as lasttrack, count(DISTINCT track_create_time) as totaldays FROM user_tracks GROUP BY username ORDER BY usertracklength DESC";
$totalResult = mysql_query($totalQuery);
$rankResult = mysql_query($totalQuery);
$totalNumEntries = mysql_num_rows($totalResult);
```

Then Ouputting that to an array

```
// rank position array
$rankArray = array();

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rankResult)) {
    $rankArray[] = $row1['username'];
}
```

Then finding position of that username in the array by using a foreach in php

```
foreach ($rankArray as $rank => $user) {
    if ($user == $username) {
    $yourRank = $rank+1; 
    }
}
```

It's the long way around, but I suppose it works for what I'm going for.
Was kind of hoping to get it done within the mysql query for efficiency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look something like this.  Add the ranking logic to the outer loop.

```
select * from 
    (select user_id, sum(km_skied) as km from ski group by user_id) x
order by x.km desc;
```

Don't know if it's an option, but you can use a temporary table for rankings as follows:

```
create temporary table ranks (rank int primary key auto_increment, user_id int, km int);

insert into ranks (user_id, km) 
    select user_id, km from (
        select user_id, sum(km_skied) as km from ski group by user_id
    ) x order by x.km desc;
```

This gives you what you want:

```
mysql> select * from ranks;
+------+---------+------+
| rank | user_id | km   |
+------+---------+------+
|    1 |       1 |   37 |
|    2 |       4 |   23 |
|    3 |       3 |    7 |
+------+---------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

One downside to this approach is that skiers who are tied won't get the same rank.

Answer (score 0):

Do the grouping in subquery and ranking of the results (using any of the methods you've found before) in outer query.

Comment: That requires an ORDER BY in a subquery, which doesn't make sense since relations _should_ be sets (unordered by definition). But I don't know any other way with MySQL, sadly.

Comment: I did find a solution to the first part, ranking by group using :  <code>"SELECT SUM(track_length) as usertracklength, username, MAX(track_create_time) as lasttrack, count(DISTINCT track_create_time) as totaldays FROM mv_user_tracks GROUP BY username ORDER BY usertracklength DESC";</code> then using PHP to print out the results in an ordered list.  What I do need to find is the rank for individuals so I can print out something like "Your Rank: 2 out of 100".

Answer (score 0):

You could try grouping to sum the Km as a first query, then follow it by a correlated subquery to find the ranks. For instance, if your values are stored in a table called "test", sum the Km values into a table called testtbl and then do the ranking.

mysql> select * from test;
+------+--------+------+
| Id   | km_run | name |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 |     34 | a    |
|    3 |      2 | c    |
|    1 |      3 | a    |
|    4 |     23 | d    |
|    3 |      5 | c    |
+------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table testtbl as 
(select Id, sum(km_run) as tot 
from test 
group by Id);

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from testtbl;
+------+------+
| Id   | tot  |
+------+------+
|    1 |   37 |
|    3 |    7 |
|    4 |   23 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select t1.Id,t1.tot,
((select count(distinct t2.tot) from testtbl t2 where t1.tot < t2.tot)+1) as Rk from testtbl t1
 order by Rk;
+------+------+------+
| Id   | tot  | Rk   |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |   37 |    1 |
|    4 |   23 |    2 |
|    3 |    7 |    3 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)